# Azure Heml Init task fail to find kubectl

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm

Over the night all our builds and releases pipelines failed due to introducing the new Helm Install task or 3.0 Helm release. We manage to fix Helm install by using the *1 version in preview and install last working helm which was 2.16.0. After that our task Heml Init failed because it cannot find the kubectl. Yesterday everything was working fine. This is happening across our all builds and releases. Directory in which it trying to find kubectl is empty for some reason. Did something changed over the night?

Log:

````
2019-11-14T10:22:21.1487212Z ##[debug]Kubeconfig file path: C:\agent\_work\_temp\helmTask\1573726941144\config
2019-11-14T10:22:21.1494250Z ##[debug]which 'kubectl'
2019-11-14T10:22:21.1574073Z ##[debug]not found
2019-11-14T10:22:21.1576552Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2019-11-14T10:22:21.1634103Z ##[error]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'kubectl'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.
2019-11-14T10:22:21.1641140Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'kubectl'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.
2019-11-14T10:22:21.1642296Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'kubectl'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.```
````

Comment: Yes, we do some commits last night, and what we changed also be the path of helmTool. See https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/commit/cf55c07170a4447929c038325b4a6dee933aa8f0 Does the error still occur now? Not sure whether your error is caused by our pr is merging or because of the pr finished and script changed. Could you re-run again and check whether it is still exists now?

Comment: We've updated the k8s and the helm task to install 3.0.0 and stil we've got problem but another one now. With helm init. 2019-11-18T08:34:47.4616575Z ##[error]Error: unknown flag: --upgrade

Comment: PS. We're doing this on the self host VM as agent, could this cause problems?

Comment: So the previous error disappeared, and now there has another error occurred now? If this, could you update this ticket as the new error message(Better is completed log)?

Comment: I've added the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add checkLatestHemlVersion to false:

```
- task: HelmInstaller@0
   displayName: 'Install Helm 2.16.1'
   inputs:
     helmVersion: 2.16.1
     checkLatestHelmVersion: false
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now, since Azure Kubernetes supported version was set to 1.23.12, you should use version 1 in Azure Release Pipeline which is relevant for new k8s environment